# Android : Whatsapp : how to get all users "status"?

Tags: android, whatsapp

Friends
i want to get all my whatsapp user status which are they added.
like , busy, at home  etc..

i know there is unofficial 2 library available for whatsapp api
1.  yowsup : https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup
2.  venomous : https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

i want to know that, can i get user's status from that library ?

i know that i have another way, i can do this via 
whatsapp db.

if yes, than how. ?
i want to show all user status in listview

thanks in advance

Comment: How can I know? You try and let me know.

Comment: Hi Gauraw Yadaw, Thanks for the comment, thats what i am asking here, i want to know the process only.  Thanks